# IE8 Background Cutoff

Tags: cross-browser, width, background-image, css

I have a website that is using a div to display a background image across the screen, I have nothing in the div, but I am specifying a height.

My code looks like:

```
<div id="nav">
    <!-- -->
</div>
```

My css looks like:

```
/* Navigation */
#nav {
    background: url("images/bgnav.png") repeat-x;
    height: 116px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

what I don't understand is the fact that in Safari and FireFox the background image spans the width of my browser, but in IE8 it stops after about 1000px or so and it's not in another div...it's all by itself and there is no other code than what I posted. It'll go longer if I specify a width in pixels, but if I don't specify a width or if the width is in a percentage like 100% it doesn't work. I also tried to set a min-width to the width of the image, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas...this seems to only affect IE8. I tested on multiple machines that are both running IE8 and they both have the same issue, so there is no browser cache going on here.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: seems to run fine in my browser even in IE7 mode, only difference being that in IE7 mode a Vertical scrollbar appears even though it is DISABLED. All other modes IE8, IE9, IE10 all the same edge to edge or as close as is possible.

Comment: I have another container with a width of 1600px that seems to be causing the issue for ie8...because it's wider than my browser (1440x900), it looks like ie stops that navigation after 1440px (because that is the size of my browser), but keeps going for the element that's 1600px. How do I get the top element to span across the entire screen and not stop at 1440px...anyone ever seen this?

Comment: post the relevant code for the size 1600px image bits, or alternatively its more recommended that you shorten the 1600px element to 1440 UNLESS you REALLY need it? The only way I can see it being needed is if your targeting Full Hd 1920*1080 screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @Zaf Khan's advice and reworked my website to be compliant with a smaller screen resolution. I did like the original code, but I'm glad I changed it because I have optimized it for more screen sizes :-) and even though it looks a little different than before it functions much better!

Thanks,
Josh